# Random CGPoint(s)

Tags: math, core-graphics

How could I get a random CGPoint that is outside the screen boundaries (frame)?

Also, given that point, how could I find a symmetrical point to it to the middle of the screen- e.g. say I have the point (width+1,height+1). Now the symmetrical point is (-1,-1). Say I have (-1,height +1)- symmetrical would be (width+1,-1).

Hope this is clear, and thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"outside the screen boundary"*? Your examples `(width,height)` and `(0,height)` are not outside but on the boundary.

Comment: My bad, either edges or outside. Preferably outside. I'll edit

Comment: OK, but what should the possible range of the random points be?

Comment: Everywhere outside the boundaries of the screen

Comment: But you have to specify some limit. What should a "random point somewhere in the plane" be?

Comment: Well, you can compute a random point, then test to see if it's outside the frame.  Or you can compute a random point and "push" it outside if it's inside.  The latter approach would be harder to make truly random, though.

Comment: Sorry! My domain should be x<0 || y<0 || x>width || y>height

Comment: @harrym17: You have to specify some limit (e.g. -1e10 < x < 1e10 and -1e10 < y < 1e10) or specify some probability distribution (e.g. points near the origin are more like than points far far away). - But "a random point somewhere in the x/y plane" without any restrictions does not make sense. - Does that make sense for you? Let me know if I can do more to help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the following method:

```
- (CGPoint) randomPointIn:(CGRect)inrect outsideOf:(CGRect)outrect
{
    CGPoint p;
    do {
        p.x = inrect.origin.x + inrect.size.width * (float)arc4random()/(float)UINT32_MAX;
        p.y = inrect.origin.y + inrect.size.height * (float)arc4random()/(float)UINT32_MAX;
    } while (CGRectContainsPoint(outrect, p));
    return p;
}
```

It returns a random point that is inside `inrect`, but outside of `outrect`.
(I have assumed that `inrect` is "considerably larger" than `outrect`,
otherwise many loop iterations might be necessary to find a valid point.)

In your case, you would use `outrect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)`,
and `inrect` would specify the allowed domain.

And the point symmetrical to `(x, y)` with respect to the middle of the screen
with size `(width, height)` is `(width - x, height - y)`.

**UPDATE:** As I just found here: http://openradar.appspot.com/7684419, 
`CGRectContainsPoint` will return false if you provide it a point that is on the boundary of the `CGRect`. That means that the above method returns a point that is outside of
or *on the boundary* of the given rectangle `outrect`. If that is not desired, 
additional checks can be added.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this should work.

```
//To get a random point
- (CGPoint)randomPointOutside:(CGRect)rect
{
    // arc4random()%(int)rect.size.width
    // This gets a random number within the width of the rectangle
    //
    // (arc4random()%2) ? rect.size.width : 0)
    // This has a 50:50 to put the point in the q1 quadrant relative to the top right point of the rect
    //
    //    q4       q1
    //   _____ +  
    //  |     |
    //  | q3  |    q2
    //  |_____|
    //
    float x = arc4random()%(int)rect.size.width + ((arc4random()%2) ? rect.size.width : 0);
    float y = arc4random()%(int)rect.size.height + ((arc4random()%2) ? rect.size.height : 0);
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

//To get the symmetrical point
- (CGPoint)symmetricalPoint:(CGPoint)p around:(CGRect)rect
{
    return CGPointMake((p.x-rect.size.width) * -1, (p.y-rect.size.height) * -1);
}
```

Comment: Your method returns a random point in any of the quadrants q1, q2, q3, q4 and that may well be inside the given rectangle. Also your code ignores the *origin* of the rectangle.